# Unable to install sklearn==1.1.2 on a remote server

Tags: python, linux, installation, scikit-learn, dependencies

> apolloadmin@apollo-nginxlb-scale-vm:/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi$
> python model_v4_deploy.py
> /home/apolloadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:315:
> UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator ExtraTreeRegressor from
> version 1.2.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking
> code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   UserWarning)
> /home/apolloadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:315:
> UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator IsolationForest from version
> 1.2.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   UserWarning)
> /home/apolloadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:315:
> UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator StandardScaler from version
> 1.2.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   UserWarning) Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "model_v4_deploy.py", line 242, in 
> users_today['pred']=loaded_model.predict(loaded_scaler.transform(users_today.drop('mobilenumber',axis=1).fillna(0)))
> File
> "/home/apolloadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/*iforest.py",
> line 314, in predict
> is_inlier[self.decision_function(X) < 0] = -1   File "/home/apolloadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/*iforest.py",
> line 347, in decision_function
> return self.score_samples(X) - self.offset*   File "/home/apolloadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/*iforest.py",
> line 379, in score_samples
> if self.n_features* != X.shape[1]: AttributeError: 'IsolationForest' object has no attribute 'n_features*'
> apolloadmin@apollo-nginxlb-scale-vm:/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi$
> pip install sklearn Defaulting to user installation because normal
> site-packages is not writeable Requirement already satisfied: sklearn
> in /home/apolloadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.0.post1)
> apolloadmin@apollo-nginxlb-scale-vm:/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi$
> pip install scikit-learn 1.2.2 Defaulting to user installation because
> normal site-packages is not writeable Requirement already satisfied:
> scikit-learn in /home/apolloadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
> (0.24.2) ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the
> requirement 1.2.2 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching
> distribution found for 1.2.2
> apolloadmin@apollo-nginxlb-scale-vm:/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi$
> pip install scikit-learn==1.2.2 Defaulting to user installation
> because normal site-packages is not writeable ERROR: Could not find a
> version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn==1.2.2 (from
> versions: 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.14, 0.14.1,
> 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17, 0.17.1, 0.18, 0.18.1, 0.18.2, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.20.4, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.21.2, 0.21.3, 0.22, 0.22.1, 0.22.2, 0.22.2.post1, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2) ERROR: No matching distribution found for scikit-learn==1.2.2

Why might this be , how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using **python 3.6**, but **sklearn 1.2.2** requires **python >=3.8** ([link](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/1.2.2/)).
You can either use sklearn 0.24.2, or need to use python >=3.8.